# Specify ConnectionString for MVC DataContext globally

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, connection-string, datacontext

I have an MVC3 Application that allows a user to choose the database they want to use on initial login. 
The various connection strings are available in the web.config
I would like every DataContext to use the chosen connection.

I am aware that I can supply a parameter to one instance of a named DataContext like this:

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext(ConnectionString);
```

or I can override the OnCreated event for all instances of a named DataContext

```
public partial class MyDataContext
{
    partial void OnCreated()
    {
        Connections connections = new Connections();
        this.Connection.ConnectionString = connections.GetCurrentConnectionString();
    }
}
```

how about all instances of all DataContexts throughout the application?

Comment: is this linq to sql or linq to entities? Code first or DB first?